# Which layout to use for putting pieces of a jigsaw puzzle in android?

Tags: android

I am creating a jigsaw puzzle game, the pieces of jigsaw overlap with each other as shown in attached image. So which layout in android allows such ordering of pieces?[image]

Comment: What about no layout? `Canvas`

Comment: The pieces do not overlap. As usual they don't. Just normal puzzle.